# Comparing byte array hex values in c#

Tags: c#, hex, arrays

I am making C# windows application.In that application i have one byte array containing hex values.suppose i have byte array as

```
 array[0]=4E
 array[1]=50
```

Here i want to combination of these values as `4E50` to compare.I dont want to compare single byte.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean - you've got two bytes - what are you trying to compare them *with*, and what do you want the result to be?

Comment: where do you geht the hex from, and in wich format?

Comment: I just want to take combination of these two bytes and compare it with other number for further processing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly do you want to compare 0x4E50 with another number? If so you can do as follows:

```
(array[0] << 8) + array[1]
```

This will give you 0x4E50.

Comment: And this will be very fast, too.

Comment: No worries, if you need to add another just keep in mind that shifting by four bytes is basically multiplying by 16 so 0xF<<4=0xF0. If you want to add another two byte number, simply shift by 16, then by 24, ect.

Comment: @Godwin nice solution, better then mine. +1

Comment: @Godwin see my answer (inspired by yours).

Answer (score 2):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (byte b in array)
{
       sb.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b)
}
return sb.ToString();
```

### edit

inspired by Godwin solution , but better :

```
(array[0] << 8) | array[1]
```